# Taylor Expansion of Function $x^2e^x$

Tags: calculus

What is the Taylor expansion of the function $x^2e^x$?

I know the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, but I don't get how to form the Taylor expansion for $x^2e^x$ Taylor expansion.....can you help me?? Thanks...

Comment: Take the Taylor expansion for $e^x$ and multiply by $x^2$.

Comment: Taylor series at what point?  (The answers seem to assume at point $0$.)

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2e^x=x^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+2}}{k!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- What is the Taylor series for $e^{x}$? Write out the first few terms of it, say, to the 5th term.
- Calculate the first few derivatives of $x^{2}e^{x}$. Plug in zero to get the first few terms of the Taylor series about $0$.
- Make an educated guess about about what the Taylor series for $x^{2}e^{x}$ should look like. Why should your guess be true? Can you prove your guess generally for two functions with a well defined Taylor series?

Feel free to post or comment if you need more hints!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the series

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k+2}}{k!}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{(k-2)!},  $$

by shifting the index $k$.